# Windows Assembly (x86) Read from Stdin and output to Stdout

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, stdout, stdin

I recently figured out how to write to stdout in assembly but am now having trouble reading from stdin, and outputting what I read back to stdout. This is the code I have so far:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall

WriteFile PROTO STDCALL:DWORD, :PTR, :DWORD, :PTR DWORD, :PTR OVERLAPPED
ReadFile  PROTO STDCALL:DWORD, :PTR, :DWORD, :PTR DWORD, :PTR OVERLAPPED
GetStdHandle PROTO STDCALL:DWORD
.data


.data?
input DW ?
input_size DD ?
read DD ?

.code
main:
    INVOKE GetStdHandle, -10
    INVOKE ReadFile, eax, OFFSET input, input_size, read, 0
    INVOKE GetStdHandle, -11
    INVOKE WriteFile, eax, OFFSET input, OFFSET input_size, read, 0
    RET 
END main
```

I'm pretty sure I'm reading it wrong. I am pretty sure that `input_size` and `read` are not behaving as expected (if I replace `input_size` with a `number` it displays a space `number` times) which is contributing to my problem (when I enter my input and hit return it simply displays nothing).

I have fumbled around with this for quite some time and would appreciate any help. (I am doing this just to learn this is not homework).

My question essentialy is what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating only two bytes for the input buffer:

```
input DW ?
```

Your input size is zero, causing ReadFile to read a maximum of 0 bytes:

```
input_size DD ?
```

nNumberOfBytesToRead should be passed as a value and not a pointer. And you want to write as many bytes as were input in the Readfile:

```
INVOKE WriteFile, eax, OFFSET input, OFFSET input_size, read, 0
INVOKE WriteFile, eax, OFFSET input, read, read, 0
```